# How would I multiply the values of two select options without using a submit button in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My goal here is to use the two drop down boxes to select a service and a discount amount. This will display the discount and total in the two text boxes. I am fairly new to asp.net and c#, and am confused as to how I can do this calculation.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Part2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.Part2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style ="text-align: CENTER">
Please Select A Service: <select id="numA" onchange="totalA(this.value);">
    <option value="">Select your service</option>
    <option value="125">Makeover</option>
    <option value="60">Hair Styling</option>
    <option value="35">Manicure</option>
    <option value="200">Permanent Makeup</option>   
</select>
<br/><br/>
Select Your Discount: <select id="NumB" onchange="totalB(this.value);">
    <option value="">Select the discount</option>
    <option value="0">0%</option>
    <option value=".1">10%</option>
    <option value=".2">20%</option>  
    </select>
    <br/><br/>
Discount Coupon: <input id="discount" name="showTotal" type="text" value="$0.00" size="10" readonly="";/>
Grand Total: <input id="total" name="showTotal" type="text" value="$0.00" size="10" readonly=""/>
<br/><br/>     
        </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the .cs I am working on, I know I have to use if (!IsPostBack) { but I do not know how to implement it the way I need to.

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
public partial class Part2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) { 

        }
    }
}
}
```

Here's the working project in HTML for reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var numA = 0;
function totalA(valA) {
    if (valA) {
        numA = Number(valA);}
    var disc = numB*numA;
    var totalCost = (numA - disc); 
        document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + totalCost.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("discount").value = "$" + disc.toFixed(2);}
var numB = 0;
function totalB(valB) {
    if (valB) {
        numB = Number(valB);}
    var disc =  numB*numA;
    var totalCost = (numA - disc);
    document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + totalCost.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("discount").value = "$" + disc.toFixed(2);}   
</script>       
</head>
<div align="center">
<br>
<form name id="Main">
<select id="numA" placeholder="Please select a service" onchange="totalA(this.value);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your service</option>
    <option value="125">Makeover</option>
    <option value="60">Hair Styling</option>
    <option value="35">Manicure</option>
    <option value="200">Permanent Makeup</option>   
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="NumB" placeholder="Please select the discount" onchange="totalB(this.value);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select the discount</option>
    <option value="0">0%</option>
    <option value=".1">10%</option>
    <option value=".2">20%</option>  
    </select>
    <br><br>
<td>Discount Coupon: <input id="discount" name="showTotal" type="text" value="$0.00" size="10" readonly/></td>
<td>Grand Total: <input id="total" name="showTotal" type="text" value="$0.00" size="10" readonly=""/></td>
<br><br>
</form>
<hr>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the issue if html and javascript is working correctly ?  You can use the same code for your requirement.

Comment: Why you want this in C# ? you can do this in javascript and when button is clicked get the value of discount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get your question but i'll try it ..

Make one function like below

```
function multi()
{
  var drop1=document.getElementById("numA").value;
  var drop2=document.getElementById("NumB").value;
  var disc = drop1*drop2;
  var totalCost = (drop1- disc); 
  document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + totalCost.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("discount").value = "$" + disc.toFixed(2);
}
```

and your dropdown will be like

```
<select id="numA" onchange="multi();">
<option value="">Select your service</option>
<option value="125">Makeover</option>
<option value="60">Hair Styling</option>
<option value="35">Manicure</option>
<option value="200">Permanent Makeup</option>   
</select>

<select id="NumB" placeholder="Please select the discount" onchange="multi();">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select the discount</option>
<option value="0">0%</option>
<option value=".1">10%</option>
<option value=".2">20%</option>  
</select>
```

Syntax can be wrong, i am just giving you an idea.

I hope it helps...

**Update**

let me give an example if you would use server control

your .aspx page will look like below

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNumA" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlnumA_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select your service</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="125">Makeover</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="60">Hair Styling</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="35">Manicure</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="200">Permanent Makeup</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNumB" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlNumB_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select the discount</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">0%</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value=".1">10%</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value=".2">20%</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtdiscount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txttotal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and here is your c# file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        multi();
    }
}

public void  multi()
{
  if(ddlnumA.SelectedValue!="-1" && ddlNumB.SelectedValue!="-1")
  {

    Decimal NumA=Convert.ToDecimal(ddlNumA.SelectedValue);
    Decimal NumB=Convert.ToDecimal(ddlNumB.SelectedValue);
    Decimal disc = NumA*NumB;
    Decimal totalCost = (NumA- disc ); 
    txttotal.Text = "$" + totalCost.ToString();
    txtdiscount.Text = "$" + disc.ToString();
  } 


}

//here are the change events of dropdown
protected void ddlnumA_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   multi();    
}
protected void ddlNumB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   multi();    
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work in a working .cs file. The code you provided is basically what I currently have coded in HTML. My goal here is to get the same result but using asp.net and c# instead of HTML/Javascript.

Comment: if you want to code in c#, then you have to use server control instead of html control. here your dropdown list is html control

Comment: How would I convert to server control?

Comment: I am receiving only one error here. I am getting that ddlnumA does not exist in the current context. How would I define this here? Thank you for the answer, by the way. I understand what you mean by server control now.

Comment: replace ddlnumA with ddlNumA.